# html5 apps for tablets: possible to load images from device's filesystem?

Tags: android, ios, html, storage

I created a simple html file that loads some images from my local hard-drive (ubuntu). 
It is enough to put

```
 <img src=/home/user/directory/image.jpg></img>
```

Now I need to know if it is the same when Html5 is displayed on a tablet like Android or iOS, or Html5 is used in offline app.
I mean, if html5 can load an image from the device's filesystem just like on my computer, without localStorage or sessionStorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android, it can be done even though it looks a bit tricky at first. Say you have defined a WebView in your layout.xml, which you want to fill with an html file shipped with your application, which in turn should import a png also shipped with your application.

The trick is to put the html file into `res/raw` and the png into `assets`.

Example.

Say you have `hello.html` which should include `buongiorno.png`.

1. Within your project, say `MyProject`, place `buongiorno.png` into `MyProject/assets`.
2. The `hello.html` goes into `MyProject/res/raw` (because we want to avoid having it 'optimised' by the android resource compiler), and could look like this:

   ```
   <html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
     <img src="file:///android_asset/buongiorno.png"/>
     <p>Hello world.</p>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

In your java code, you would put this code:

```
    WebView w = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebview);
    String html = getResourceAsString(context, R.raw.hello);
    if (html != null) {
        w.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
    }
```

where `getResourceAsString()` is defined as follows:

```
public static String getResourceAsString(Context context, int resid) throws NotFoundException {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    InputStream is = resources.openRawResource(resid);
    try {
        if (is != null && is.available() > 0) {
            final byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
            is.read(data);
            return new String(data);
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // ignore
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you deploy the application as native application it is possible (wrap it with Phonegap).

For saved HTML files it is not possible.

Comment: I think all PhoneGap does, programmers can do too, which is the trick under?

Comment: You did not tell that you are developing using WebView - I assume you had 0% native application experience